# Programatically calling all methods in a Java class

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to go through a large amout of classes with variable methods and have each method run with some generated input.  It doesn't really matter what the result is, it only matters that there aren't any errors.

I have this code to find all methods and invoke them:

```
MyClassType theClass = new MyClassType();  // Fake class for example
Method[] methods = theClass.getClass().getMethods();

for (Method m : methods) {
    try {
        m.invoke(theClass, new Object[]{});
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Log error
    }
}
```

This works fine for all methods that do not take any arguments, but fails for methods that do.

Is there any way I can programatically detect the type of arguments needed for each method and give it a test value?  For example, all booleans are `true`, all ints are `1`, all floats are `1.5f`, etc.

Comment: Look further into reflection, since it can get the argument types for your class's methods.

Comment: What about custom types? What default value do you use for that?

Comment: I looked at the documentation for this, but, as usual, it's a massive program that far escapes my grasp of beginner's Java.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Method API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html), .... which to be honest really should have been the first place you should look before coming here actually. The `getParametertypes()` method in the Method class will help. There are other useful methods present there including those that help with generic methods.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that.  Thank you, will mark as correct in 9 minutes.